# Recover ubuntu after deleting the /usr directory

Tags: data-recovery

I was trying to fix a problem with permissions to read a usb stick in Ubuntu 18.04 by mounting in a directory created /media/usb. It didn´t solve my issue and I tried to remove the usb directory from /media. In that moment I had root privileges in /media an I made a mistake typing rm -R /usr instead rm -R /usb. After that, I lose all my shortcuts and my entire graphical environment. I restarted my computer and kernel doesn´t permit Ubuntu to start.

How can I recover Ubuntu at this point?

Comment: What backup strategy did you choose?   A re-install using 'something-else' using existing partitions but without format is probably fastest & easiest (assuming you have no backup strategy); it'll take note of your added programs, wipe system directories, install then add-back your added software.  *Whatever you had in /usr/ will vary on what you installed & thus is install specific*

Comment: Thank for answer guiverc. I have not a backup strategy. I have a code installed in my session and I would like to do not lose it. Which strategy can you recommend?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *code install in my session* sorry, but the re-install using something-else without format doesn't touch anything in your $HOME (home user directory), and thus won't modify user settings for nearly everything.  Because it erases system directories, it's possible some global configs will be lost (but you've already erased everything in /usr so anything there is already gone). I would chalk this up as a learning exercise (be-careful with `sudo`, and maybe you'll realize know why 'root' should be avoided in future).

Comment: fyi: Your existing session if it had /usr/ open files, can still access the data there via inodes, which won't be gone (marked for re-use) until files are closed (be it program end, logout or reboot), thus the full effect of what you've done won't be noticed until next session.